# Clickhouse system.parts table column definitions

Tags: database, metrics, tablecolumn, clickhouse

I am currently gathering metrics from Clickhouse's system tables and when grabbing information from the system.parts table there are a bunch of columns listed that are not documented, can anyone help explain what the following columns represent:

- level
- primary_key_bytes_in_memory
- primary_key_bytes_in_memory_allocated

I am specifically interested in knowing the primary key's index size, but am having trouble determining the difference between the two primary key columns above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- **level** - depth of the merge tree that formed part. It's 0 for newly
  created part, and is calculated as max of levels after merge
- **primary_key_bytes_in_memory** - total size of index in bytes (may be
  approximate)
- **primary_key_bytes_in_memory_allocated** - total size of memory,
  allocated for index

Since index is stored in memory, it's expected that **primary_key_bytes_in_memory_allocated** >= **primary_key_bytes_in_memory**. It's connected with difference between *capacity* and *size* for standard containers.

Comment: Thanks @Nikolai Kochetov I was wondering if you may be able to help me out with a few others, I've asked the Yandex team about but haven't heard back yet.

- system.events
- system.metrics
- system.asynchronous_metrics

I am trying to achieve the equivalent of gathering the following metrics http://docs.datadoghq.com/integrations/postgresql/#metrics to report on but do not know which fields represent what.